# What is causing private method `gsub` called for nil:NilClass during Rails migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, jruby, rvm

I've never sent this one before. I'm configuring a new server with an existing application. Trying to run a migration and here's the output.

```
root@beta:/vol/opt/dev/capistrano/foo-alpha/releases/20120330233010# RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
private method `gsub' called for nil:NilClass
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `require'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1614:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
/vol/opt/dev/capistrano/foo-alpha/releases/20120330233010/config/application.rb:7:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/vol/opt/dev/capistrano/foo-alpha/releases/20120330233010/config/application.rb:4:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052:in `load'
/vol/opt/dev/capistrano/foo-alpha/releases/20120330233010/Rakefile:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1052:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.6@foo/bin/rake:19:in `(root)'
```

Migrations on my local laptop and on an existing server are working fine. config/database.yml looks right. Database is up and running and I can connect to it. What is this?

I also just tested `rails console` and I'm also not able to get a console. Again a private method `gsub` called for nil:NilClass. It's somehow related to connecting to the database and I'm not sure how/why.

** UPDATE **

After adding some debug into runtime.rb, this is the exception that's being raised:

```
#<LoadError: no such file to load -- activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter>
```

The messed up part is, it is installed:

```
# gem list |grep -i activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter
activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter (1.2.2)
```

Is this some kind of RVM or bundler bug?

** LAST UPDATE **

I installed Amazon Linux AMI (The other is running an Ubuntu) and cannot replicate this issue there.

Comment: I have a ton of migrations. All of which have worked fine so far until I setup a new server.

Comment: Have you tried running this code under a different ruby implementation?

Comment: have you tried running the migrations in a different environment?  It is possible you are missing some environment based value set based on RAILS_ENV

Comment: Yes, if you read my post, you'll see the migrations (and everything else) works on different environments. To be more specific, it works fine on a RHEL box, my OSX laptop. It's having issues on a new Ubuntu server.

Comment: but have you tried building a dev env on the production box.  Often times when you have issues moving between boxes it is that you are using a different Env or that you are missing a gem or other dependency.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in bundler, it was reported for rvm-capistrano, please check your Gemfile and try removing / commenting some gems.

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1801

Comment: Seriously dude, no link? Just  a 'try commenting out some gems?!' Why even post an answer at all?